# Photoshop layer blending - null out background

Tags: photoshop, layer, blending, image-masking

Is it possible using layer blending and maybe masking to null out the background(transparent) using a picture with the product in place and one without the product as a background reference picture.

Like a layer mask that only reveals where images are different. (Product and shadow)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this question about photoshop scripting ? The idea should work assuming the camera position, lighting and background doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Totally possbile but i'm not sure you'll get the desired effect.  If you want to subtract absolutely just the areas where there are color differences that means shadow edges will be pixelated. Nonetheless, here's how you do it

Set up your layers like so:

```
Layer 1 (background + product baked in on top)
Layer 2 (background only)
```

Set Layer 1 blending mode to "Difference" --All the pixels with the same color information will turn black.

Flatten this and we'll call it "Layer 3 (Difference)"

Go into Layer 3's FX Styles. Under Blending Options, all the way at the bottom you'll find "Blend if:"

Set this to Gray and slide the "This layer:" markers until it says 0 0.
Voila. You have the mask to put on your original Layer 1 that eliminates all pixels with the same information.

[image: Blending Mode]